# trie implementation in go using maps

Tags: go, maps, trie

I am trying to implement the Trie data structure using go but I am not that familiar with the language nor using a map and was wondering if there were some tips to how I can factor out some of my recursion so it doesn't look so bad. Also would appreciate it if I could get some help on how to make just the add method better (less lines of code).

Just noticed the problem where the tree itself would never know when a word is added so definitely a solution to that would be great!

```
// The overall tree
type TrieTree struct { 
    root TrieNode
    count int
}

// The node for each character inside the tree
type TrieNode struct {
    letter string // this is the value of the current node 
    isWord bool // if this letter + all of its parents make a word set = to true 
    children map[string]*TrieNode // maps children nodes
}

//method for adding a word into the tree
func (root *TrieNode) AddEntry (entry string) {
    //in case someone is trying to mess you up
    if (entry != nil || len(entry) != 0 || root != nil) {
        entry = strings.ToLower(entry)
        AddEntryHelper(root, entry, 0)
    }
}

func (node *TrieNode) AddEntryHelper (entry string, count int) {
    // the last one and no child yet
    if(node.children == nil && count == len(entry)-1) { 
        node.children=(map[string(entry[count])]=TrieNode{string(entry[count]), true, nil})
    // no children and not last one
    } else if(node.children == nil && count != len(entry)-1) { 
        node.children=(map[string(entry[count])]=TrieNode{string(entry[count]), false, nil})
        AddEntryHelper(node.children[string(entry[count])], entry, count++) 
    // last one and child exist
    } else if (node.children != nil && count == len(entry)-1) {
        node.children[string(entry[count])].isWord = true
    // children node exists and just need to recurse down
    } else {
        AddEntryHelper(node.children[string(entry[count])], entry, count++)
    }
}
```

Comment: A couple of things: 1) You don't want to add an entry to a specific node, but to the whole Trie. 2) Typically, you'd implement something like a `walk` method that takes the next character and returns the corresponding node, you would use it to find a place for the new entry. 3) There are already implementations of a Trie in go. 4) If you want to do it right, use a double array implementation, see http://linux.thai.net/~thep/datrie/datrie.html

Comment: You are using multiple receivers in your methods, this won't work. Use something like: `func (root *TrieNode) AddEntry(entry string)` if you want to use methods, or `func AddEntry(root *TrieNode, entry string)` if you want plain functions.